# Tesseract OCR engine configuration for increased performance

Tags: performance, optimization, text, ocr, tesseract

I have written a short batch file to perform OCR on over 20K screenshot images using the [Tesseract open-source OCR engine](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract).

Everything works well, except I would like to increase performance of the Tesseract OCR engine.  Everything with OCR is a trade-off between speed and accuracy, and for this particular task, I'm fine increasing speed at the cost of accuracy.

All that is required is rough OCR output; thus 75% accuracy is acceptable for this task.

I've been trying to find some good tips on what to include in a Tesseract configuration file to increase the OCR engine's performance, but the info I could find online is limited, and much of it only applies to v2 or v3 of Tesseract.  I'm hoping people here can help with more current info, especially info pertaining to v4 or v5 of Tesseract.

In addition to my willingness to reduce OCR accuracy for this task, there are some guarantees concerning the content of the images that may present *further optimization opportunities*:

- the text in all images is oriented in the left to right direction
- the text in all images is only in the English language
- the font size of all text that needs to be identified is always at least 10pt
- every image is a screenshot from a modern web browser, and thus the text is all well-rendered text (meaning there is no blurriness from a camera or scanner, nor any skewing or image curvature)
- only letters are important; numbers, punctuation, and symbols do not matter
- the maximum horizontal resolution of each image is 1920px
- there is no consistent vertical resolution of each image, but 1080px is the most common size; I'm willing to limit OCR to the top 800px of each image

I have already tried limiting the range of different characters that Tessaract needs to recognize, but this made no performance difference.

Comment: Not sure if this also applies to Windows, but which version of Tesseract do you use, the single-threaded or the multi-threaded: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/3109

Answer (score 0):

You should try running parallel instances of Tesseract on all available cores with OMP_THREAD_LIMIT set to 1. Or, you can build Tesseract applying the appropriate configuration as mentioned [here](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Compiling-%E2%80%93-GitInstallation.html#release-builds-for-mass-production). By default, multithreading is enabled in Tesseract which causes slow performance while processing multiple images due to the overhead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).